# Spring Cloud config server on git misconfiguration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I created an instance of cloud config server using the following dependencies and properties:

```
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jayway.jsonpath/json-path -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I enables the config server:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigServer
public class CloudConfigServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CloudConfigServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

So far so good. Now I also passed several configuration in application.properties:

```
server.port=8888
spring.application.name=cloud-config-service

# https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html#_git_ssh_configuration_using_properties
spring.profiles.active=git
spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=my@email.com
spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=ghp_tokenGenerated
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/me/spring-cloud-remote-configs.git
spring.cloud.config.server.git.clone-on-start=true
spring.cloud.config.server.git.force-pull=true
spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=master
spring.cloud.config.server.git.basedir=applicationName 

logging.pattern.file=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger.%M - %msg%n
logging.pattern.dateformat=yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
logging.pattern.console=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %green([%thread]) %highlight(%level)  %logger - %msg%n
logging.file.name=webapps-logs/cloud-config-service.log
logging.logback.rollingpolicy.max-history=5
logging.logback.rollingpolicy.max-file-size=1250MB
logging.level.root=INFO
logging.level.fr.dsidiff=INFO
logging.level.org.springframework=INFO

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.health.enabled=true
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
```

Actually, the files are cloned in the same folder in applicationName/applicationName
When application is started I noticed a warning message:

```
WARN  org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.EnvironmentController - Error getting the Environment with name=dsipilot profiles=discovery-service label=default includeOrigin=false
```

org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.NoSuchLabelException: No such label: default

The second step consists on using the configuration in other micro services. Here is my application.yml for a webservice using configuration:

```
server:
  port: ${PORT:0}
  forward-headers-strategy: framework

spring:
  application:
    name: users-service
  cloud:
    config:
      enabled: true
      name: ${spring.application.name}
  rabbitmq:
    host: localhost
    username: guest
    password: guest
    port: 5672
  config:
    import: "optional:configserver:${CONFIG_SERVER:http://localhost:8888}"
  datasource:
    username: root
    password: root
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        column_ordering_strategy: legacy
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: 'true'
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
  devtools:
    restart:
      enabled: true

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_SERVER:http://localhost:8761/eureka}
  instance:
    preferIpAddress: true
    instance-id: ${spring.application.name}:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}

logging:
  pattern:
    level: "%5p [${spring.application.name}, %X{traceId:-}, %X{spanId:-}]"
    dateformat: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
  file:
    name: webapps-logs/users-service.log
  logback:
    rollingpolicy:
      max-history: '5'
      max-file-size: 250MB
  level:
    root: WARN
    fr.webservices: INFO
    org.springframework: INFO
    org.hibernate: INFO

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        #include: openapi, swagger-ui, busrefresh
        include: '*'
  endpoint:
    health:
      enabled: true
      show-details: always
  tracing:
    sampling:
      probability: 1
  zipkin:
    tracing:
      endpoint: http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans

users-ws:
  message: "message from Localhost"
```

**My webservice contains the following dependency:**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**For test purpose I added the following controller method:**

```
@GetMapping
public String status() {
    String status = "Users service > Working on port " +
            env.getProperty("local.server.port") +
            "Current message: \r\n " + env.getProperty("users-ws.message");
    log.info(status);
    return status;
}
```

In the git repository I do have a users-service.yml file in the directory applicationName on github.

This file contains a different message:

```
users-ws:
  message: "message from Github"
```

My issues are the followings:

1. I do not retrieve the configuration using http://localhost:8888/users-service/default

[image]

2. I do not retrieve the message I would expect. I do guess some details of config server configuration went a little bit wrong. I just do see where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply replace

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.basedir=applicationName
```

With

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.search-paths=applicationName
```

I simply didn't pay attention when I set my properties.